# Widget child view coordinates?

Tags: android, android-widget, coordinates

In an activity we can use **getIntent()** to get coordinates of top and left corner of view that request to start an Activity:

```
top = this.getIntent().getSourceBounds().top;
left = this.getIntent().getSourceBounds().left;
```

So if a widget request to start an Activity,we can get it's top and left corner coordinates.But if a child view of widget(like a button or textview) apply to start an Activity,how we can get coordinates of top and left corner of widget?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You could check them in the same event that launches the `Intent` and pass them as an extra with this `Intent`

Comment: @Michał K :I found a way.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any method to get parent view's coordinates,so I use relative layout for widget and set textview layout_alignParentLeft and layout_alignParentTop with "true",and then set other controls in front of it.As result when user clicks on textview,textview send it's coordinates with intent that it is equal to it's parent coordinates.